# How to process each line of a CSV to a single XML output - WSO2/Smooks

Tags: xsd, wso2, freemarker, smooks, wso2-esb

**TL;DR: I have a multline CSV and I want to process line by line and generate a different XML for each line.**

**I have the following CSV:**

```
Chathuri,Wimalasena,Female,25,SriLanka
Saminda,Wijerathne,Male,26,SriLanka
Dakshitha,Rathnayaka,Female,24,SriLanka
Harsha,Martin,Male,24,SriLanka
```

**Currently I am using smooks and doing the following transformation:**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soapenv:Body>
        <people>
                <person>
                <lastname>Wimalasena</lastname>
                <firstname>Chathuri</firstname>
                <gender>Female</gender>
                <age>25</age>
                <country>SriLanka</country>
            </person>
            <person>
                <lastname>Wijerathne</lastname>
                <firstname>Saminda</firstname>
                <gender>Male</gender>
                <age>26</age>
                <country>SriLanka</country>
            </person>
            <person>
                <lastname>Rathnayaka</lastname>
                <firstname>Dakshitha</firstname>
                <gender>Female</gender>
                <age>24</age>
                <country>SriLanka</country>
            </person>
            <person>
                <lastname>Martin</lastname>
                <firstname>Harsha</firstname>
                <gender>Male</gender>
                <age>24</age>
                <country>SriLanka</country>
            </person>
        </people>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

**The questions is: I want something like this:**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soapenv:Body>
        <people>
            <person>
                <lastname>Wimalasena</lastname>
                <firstname>Chathuri</firstname>
                <gender>Female</gender>
                <age>25</age>
                <country>SriLanka</country>
            </person>
        </people>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>


<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soapenv:Body>
        <people>
            <person>
                <lastname>Wijerathne</lastname>
                <firstname>Saminda</firstname>
                <gender>Male</gender>
                <age>26</age>
                <country>SriLanka</country>
            </person>
        </people>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

**My smook.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><smooks-resource-list xmlns="http://www.milyn.org/xsd/smooks-1.1.xsd" xmlns:csv="http://www.milyn.org/xsd/smooks/csv-1.2.xsd" xmlns:ftl="http://www.milyn.org/xsd/smooks/freemarker-1.1.xsd">
  <params>
    <param name="stream.filter.type">SAX</param>
    <param name="inputType">input.csv</param>
    <param name="input.csv" type="input.type.actived">File:/C:\Users\victor.viola\Desktop\test.csv</param>
    <param name="default.serialization.on">true</param>
  </params>
  <csv:reader fields="name,surname,gender,age,country"/>
  <ftl:freemarker applyOnElement="#document">
    <ftl:template><![CDATA[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<people>
    <#list .vars["csv-set"]["csv-record"] as csv_record>
    <person>
        <lastname>${.vars["csv_record"]["surname"]}</lastname>        
        <firstname>${.vars["csv_record"]["name"]}</firstname>        
        <gender>${.vars["csv_record"]["gender"]}</gender>        
        <age>${.vars["csv_record"]["age"]}</age>        
        <country>${.vars["csv_record"]["country"]}</country>        
    </person>
    </#list>    
</people>]]></ftl:template>
    <param name="rootElementName">people</param>
    <param name="modelSrc">File:/C:\Users\victor.viola\Desktop\example.xsd</param>
    <param name="modelSrcType">XSD</param>
    <param name="messageType">XML</param>
    <param name="templateDataProvider">input</param>
  </ftl:freemarker>
  <resource-config selector="#document">
    <resource>org.milyn.delivery.DomModelCreator</resource>
  </resource-config>
</smooks-resource-list>
```

Comment: Unrelated to the question, but instead of `.vars["csv_record"]["surname"]` you can just write `csv_record.surname`. `.vars["csv-set"]["csv-record"]` is trickier because of the `-`: `csv\-set.csv\-record` (`\-` requires FreeMarker 2.3.22+).

Comment: Thank you for the tip =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With smooks, you can route messages into files or JMS queues.

Please, have a look at this sample that read the file in streaming mode and split it's content into files or JMS messages (it works in Fixed Length but this is the same with csv, just use csv:reader)

Proxy service :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="VFSProxy" transports="vfs" startOnLoad="true" trace="disable">
    <target>
        <inSequence>
            <property name="DISABLE_SMOOKS_RESULT_PAYLOAD" value="true"/>
            <smooks config-key="SmooksSplitFileFL">
            <!--smooks config-key="SmooksSplitJMSFL"-->
                <input type="text"/>
                <output type="xml"/>
            </smooks>
        </inSequence>
    </target>
    <parameter name="transport.vfs.FileURI">vfs:file:///C:/In</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.vfs.FileNamePattern">.*.fl</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.vfs.ContentType">text/plain</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.vfs.Streaming">true</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.PollInterval">15</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.vfs.ActionAfterProcess">DELETE</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.vfs.ActionAfterFailure">DELETE</parameter>
</proxy>
```

Smooks that split into files (a local-entry, firstname is used to name the file so, if there is multiples lines with the same firstname, you will have the last one)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<localEntry xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" key="SmooksSplitFileFL">
    <smooks-resource-list xmlns="http://www.milyn.org/xsd/smooks-1.1.xsd" xmlns:ftl="http://www.milyn.org/xsd/smooks/freemarker-1.1.xsd" xmlns:fl="http://www.milyn.org/xsd/smooks/fixed-length-1.3.xsd" xmlns:file="http://www.milyn.org/xsd/smooks/file-routing-1.1.xsd">
        <params>
            <param name="stream.filter.type">SAX</param>
            <param name="default.serialization.on">false</param>
        </params>
        <fl:reader fields="LASTNAME[2],FIRSTNAME[10]" skipLines="0"/>
        <resource-config selector="record">
            <resource>org.milyn.delivery.DomModelCreator</resource>
        </resource-config>
        <file:outputStream openOnElement="record" resourceName="fileSplitStream">
            <file:fileNamePattern>${.vars["record"].LASTNAME}.xml</file:fileNamePattern>
            <file:destinationDirectoryPattern>C:\Processed</file:destinationDirectoryPattern>
            <file:highWaterMark mark="-1"/>
        </file:outputStream>
        <ftl:freemarker applyOnElement="record">
            <ftl:template>/repository/resources/smooks/RecordToXML.ftl</ftl:template>
            <ftl:use>
                <ftl:outputTo outputStreamResource="fileSplitStream"/>
            </ftl:use>
        </ftl:freemarker>
    </smooks-resource-list>
    <description/>
</localEntry>
```

Smooks that split into JMS messages

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<localEntry xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" key="SmooksSplitJMSFL">
    <smooks-resource-list xmlns="http://www.milyn.org/xsd/smooks-1.1.xsd" xmlns:ftl="http://www.milyn.org/xsd/smooks/freemarker-1.1.xsd" xmlns:fl="http://www.milyn.org/xsd/smooks/fixed-length-1.3.xsd" xmlns:jms="http://www.milyn.org/xsd/smooks/jms-routing-1.2.xsd">
        <params>
            <param name="stream.filter.type">SAX</param>
            <param name="default.serialization.on">false</param>
        </params>
        <fl:reader fields="LASTNAME[2],FIRSTNAME[10]" skipLines="0"/>
        <resource-config selector="record">
            <resource>org.milyn.delivery.DomModelCreator</resource>
        </resource-config>
        <jms:router routeOnElement="record" beanId="Person" destination="dynamicQueues/TestFL">
            <jms:connection factory="QueueConnectionFactory"/>
            <jms:jndi contextFactory="org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory" providerUrl="nio://localhost:61616"/>
            <jms:highWaterMark mark="-1"/>
        </jms:router>
        <ftl:freemarker applyOnElement="record">
            <ftl:template>/repository/resources/smooks/RecordToXML.ftl</ftl:template>
            <ftl:use>
                <ftl:bindTo id="Person"/>
            </ftl:use>
        </ftl:freemarker>
    </smooks-resource-list>
    <description/>
</localEntry>
```

Template (create a file ESB_HOME/repository/resources/smooks/RecordToXML.ftl) :

```
<#assign rec = .vars["record"]>
<person>
    <lastname>${rec.LASTNAME}</lastname>
    <firstname>${rec.FIRSTNAME}</firstname>
</person>
```

Comment: Thank you and have a nice day.

Comment: When I try to replace FL for CSV Reader my file just disappear and nothing happens, not even a log. LOL

Comment: In my proxy def, ActionAfterProcess & failure are "DELETE" so, I guess there is a problem with your configuration and the file is deleted. What about esb logs ?

Comment: with csv, you must adapt smooks config, for exemple : resource-config selector="record" becomes resource-config selector="csv-record" (xml tree is not the same). This must be similar with applyOnElement="record" in ftl:freemarker and  routeOnElement="record" in jms:router or openOnElement="record" in file:outputStream

Comment: Thank you @Jean-Michel, I've noticed it. I am trying to fix right now.

Comment: (Unnecessary usage of `.vars[...]` again... strange.)